# Winter Bash の画面にハートの人文字ができるのは何か意味があるのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

Winter Bash の画面（http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com）を
しばらくおいていると、ハートの人文字ができるのは
何か意味があるのでしょうか？
また、どういう仕組みでハートができているのでしょうか？

Comment: イースターエッグです・・・って回答でいいでしょうか http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270984/286934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unaristがコメントで書いたとおり、これはただのイースターエッグです。

（[参考](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270984/286934)）

このSnippetで数字を入れたら、人たちがその数字の形になります。Winter Bash前にカウントダウンとして使われました。

```js
$(function () {
    $('#btnGO').click(function() {
        var minutes = parseInt($('#txtMinutes').val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(minutes)) {
            alert('Do not make us run NaN, please!');
        } else {
            countdown(new Date().getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#myPlaceholder {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;  }
body {
            background:#091e2f;
        }
        body, html, div, canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #fixed {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%
        }
        #container {
            width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #town {
         background: #0d2d46 url('//cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/bg-dark.png?v=16ca97a8899c') no-repeat center bottom;
         height: 180px;
            background-size:1200px;
        }
        canvas {
        }
        #cover {
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 450px;
            width: 200px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #091e2f, rgba(9, 30, 47, 0));
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/countdown.js?v=73c502a07616"></script>
<div id="myPlaceholder"><input type="text" id="txtMinutes" /><button id="btnGO" type="button">GO</button></div>
<div id="town"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="cover"></div>
        <canvas width="1200" height="450"></canvas>
    </div>
```

（[この回答よりコピペしました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270309/209637)）